# curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: java, ssl

We are using tomcat 1.7 and jdk 1.6, we are getting the below ssdl error:

> curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3
>   alert handshake failure

do we have any solution for this , do we need to update the tomcat or jdk 1.6.

Comment: Did you ever found an answer for that ?

Answer (score 0):

This error might be due to the 'https' in your link. This can be solved by following any one of the following suggestion.

- Add the website certificate in your library.(attached links might help)
- Use http instead of https in the link. Some links might not allow this in that case you have to use the first option.